# phpMyAdmin Welcome Screen , can it be changed further than just the logo?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was able to modify the logo of the default phpMyAdmin welcome screen, and am now trying to modify the text but cannot find the file it is read from.  I am new to programming and my gut tells me it would be located inside index.php but unfortunately my gut is never right!

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

That is the code in the source of the login screen, i have been searching high and low to find the php file to edit but am failing dismally.  Thanks for any/all advice on making this happen for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found very little about this online - however after enough searching I did find the answer. Incase this helps anyone else out or they want to change the default message that is displayed when you are at login screen to phpMyAdmin simply edit the .php file. In PHPMyAdmin 4.4.13.1 - you can find Username:  in libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php and on line #125 is the Welcome message you need.

Comment: He just gave the answer.